# How to overwrite a child in xml if exist?

Tags: c#, xml

I am adding some user id and their chosen image to xml file. How can I overwrite the a child if the user with same id add the data again?

This is how my xml looks

```
<userimage>
   <person>
     <id>df1bd6d6c95246a1ba7adf39b66def47</id>
     <url>~/images/batman.png</url>
   </person>
   <person>
     <id>837f2ba998ec4b78b75cc39176a23626</id>
     <url>~/images/apple.png</url>
   </person>
   <person>
     <id>df1bd6d6c95246a1ba7adf39b66def47</id>
     <url>~/images/pokemon.png</url>
  </person>
</userimage>
```

As you can see, there are two person with same id. I want that record to be replaced if any record is added with same id.

```
protected void AppendXml(XmlNode root, string id, string url)
    {
        XmlNode person = xdoc.CreateElement("person");
        root.AppendChild(person);
        XmlNode uname = xdoc.CreateElement("id");
        uname.InnerText = id;
        person.AppendChild(uname);
        XmlNode psswd = xdoc.CreateElement("url");
        psswd.InnerText = url;
        person.AppendChild(psswd);
    }

//code to write to xml
string id = DBConnection.getUserId(Session["User_ID"].ToString());
        string xmlpath = Server.MapPath("~/css/UserImage.xml");
        xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        if (File.Exists(xmlpath))
        {
            xdoc.Load(xmlpath);
            {
                XmlNodeList xnodelist = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("userimage");
                foreach (XmlNode xnode in xnodelist)
                {
                    xn = xnode.LastChild.OwnerDocument.FirstChild;
                }
                AppendXml(xn, id, btnimage.ImageUrl);
                xdoc.Save(xmlpath);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            XmlDeclaration xdeclartion = xdoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
            root = xdoc.CreateElement("userimage");
            xdoc.AppendChild(root);
            AppendXml(root,id,btnimage.ImageUrl);
            xdoc.Save(xmlpath);
        }
```

Comment: If there are duplicates which do you want to keep?  The URLs are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var xml = "<userimage><person><id>df1bd6d6c95246a1ba7adf39b66def47</id><url>~/images/batman.png</url></person><person><id>837f2ba998ec4b78b75cc39176a23626</id><url>~/images/apple.png</url></person><person><id>df1bd6d6c95246a1ba7adf39b66def47</id><url>~/images/pokemon.png</url></person></userimage>";
    var persons = DeserializeXml<Userimage>(xml);

    var personNew = new Person() { Id = "df1bd6d6c95246a1ba7adf39b66def47", Url = "asdf" };
    var person = persons.Person.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == personNew.Id);
    if (person == null)
    {
        persons.Person.Add(person);
    }
    else
    {
        person.Url = personNew.Url;
    }

    var str = persons.ToString();
```

You can serialize the XML into an array of objects first. Later, if you want to print out the XML then just call ToString() method.

```
    public T DeserializeXml<T>(string str)
    {
        var se = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        object obj;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(str))
        {
            obj = se.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return (T) obj;
    }

    public static string XmlSerializeToString(object obj)
    {
        var se = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            se.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return XmlSerializeToString(this);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "userimage")]
    public class Userimage
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "person")]
        public List<Person> Person { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return XmlSerializeToString(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry for very late reply. I am getting error in line obj = se.Deserialize(reader);

[InvalidOperationException: <userimage xmlns=''> was not expected.]


[InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2).]

Comment: [InvalidOperationException: <userimage xmlns=' '> was not expected.]

[InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2).]

Comment: Updated the answer. It was a typo.

Comment: Now I am getting this... [XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.]

Comment: This is how I load my xml `string xmlpath = Server.MapPath("~/css/UserImage.xml");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xmlpath);
            var xml = doc.InnerText;
            var persons = DeserializeXml<Userimage>(xml);`

Comment: Anything could happen inside the file which I have no visibility.